# Push View controller on button click not working

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have searched far and wide for an answer to this question and would be really grateful of some help. I have removed the rest of my application to keep the question simple.

My root view is simply a blank view with one button. It has been initialised with a `UINaviagationController`. All I want to do is to have the button push a new view onto the stack when pressed. At the moment, the button does nothing when pushed, here is my code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];  

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  

    return YES;
}
```

Then in my first view controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender
{
View2 *v2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];

}
```

The -(IBAction) is configured properly, but still nothing, any ideas?

EDIT::

I have found a workaround to this.

It seems that when trying to access the NavigationController from the root view, using [self.navigationController.... ] will not send the message to the instance of navigationController (no idea why!).

I got it working by adding an ivar to ViewController of type UINavigationController, and then setting the ivar from AppDelegate after initializing ViewController, like such:

```
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;


  //The UINavigationController declared int AppDelegate.h
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  

    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

  //Set the ivar on ViewController (navCon) to the UINavigationController we just 
  //initialized 
    self.viewController.navCon = navController;
```

Now when sending the message to the NavigationController in ViewController.m, I use the lines

```
View2 *v2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];

[navCon pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
```

This does work, but I feel as though this is not the way it should be done, any thoughts?

Comment: The blue navigation controller appears on the top of my first view, showing it is there, but just not responding!

Comment: Have you tried putting `NSLog(@"Button pressed!")` in your `switchView:` method to see if it ever gets called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is pretty messed up. You must make the navigation controller your window's `rootViewController`, not the nav controller's root view controller. Then, the line `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];` is superfluous and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, it might only be for coocs2d. But try putting this in the beginning of your implementation.

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Shouldn't be needed, it defaults to yes.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of things that could be problematic.

- You didn't connect everything in the IB.
- Your `View2` class is not a subclass of a `UIViewController` but of a `UIView` (hard to say at this point)

I would look into the first problem which is IB setup. Make sure your `touchUpInside` action connector is connected to its corresponding function `switchView` in the `UIViewController` object inside your IB file.

Comment: Hi Cyprian, thanks for your response. I have got it working, the problem seems that `[self.navigationController ...]` from the root view doesn't actually send a message to the navigationController instance. I had to give ViewController an UINavigationController ivar, then set the ivar as the navigationController instance created  in the AppDelegate, views after that seem fine, any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Refer to what Ole Begemann said, its the wrong approach to use UINavigationController in that way. You probably should use one of xcode templates to start your navigation based app and see how it works from there